# Cross platform beep on Groovy or Java

Tags: java, windows, linux, audio, groovy

I am working on a hex editor in Groovy (see http://github.com/mcmenaminadrian) and I want to give it a vi-like interface.

Accordingly it should 'beep' when, in vi-mode, the user presses the escape key.
How can I do this? If I use java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep() nothing happens (on Linux anyway) and if I use System.out.print("\007"); System.out.flush() I just get a character appearing on the console.

As this is just something to add shine to the app I don't want a lot of code (as suggested in some other answers), so maybe there is no reliable way of doing it - in which case, which option works on Windows, anyone know?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've always used `System.out.println("\b");`, should work cross-platform.

Comment: @Anders don't you mean \a I believe \b is backspace

Answer (score 0):

It's `println("\u0007")` - you forgot the \u, 
though java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep() should work - both work for me on OS X

You can also use `println((char)7)`

Also, beep() should be more portable. Are you sure that your Linux box has audio, and that the speakers are turn on / turned up?